# Change a fragment button color according to data coming from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity and a fragment. I am reading some data from xml to ArrayList inside `OnCreate` method of activity. Then I am creating a  class extends from `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

```
 public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < lstDepartmanlar.size();j++)
            {
                if(i==j) {
                    for (Departman departman : lstDepartmanlar)
                    {
                        if(departman.DepartmanEkrani.contentEquals(masaPlanIsmi[i]))
                        {
                            masaIsimleri = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (MasaDizayn masaDizayn : lstMasaDizayn) {
                                if(masaDizayn.MasaPlanAdi.contentEquals(departman.DepartmanEkrani)) {
                                    masaIsimleri.add(masaDizayn.MasaAdi);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    fragment = newInstance(masaIsimleri,acikMasalar);

                }
            }
            return fragment;
        }
   public static FragmentMasaDesing newInstance(ArrayList<String> masalar,String[] acikMasalar) {
    FragmentMasaDesing myFragment = new FragmentMasaDesing();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray("acikMasalar",acikMasalar);
    args.putStringArrayList("masalar", masalar);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);
    return myFragment;
}
```

Here is my FragmentPagerAdapter and newInstance method.

Also I am adding `Actionbar` tabs according to size of `lstDepartments`.

In newInstance method I am putting a list and a string array to send them while creating the fragment. It works fine at first run. If `lstDepartmanlar.size()` is three I create three layout according to data in list. When I swipe between tabs the requested layout is called and shown with no problem after creation.

Each layout has number of buttons and I want to change some buttons' color according to data coming from tcp to my activity after a tab is swiped. When I swipe tab I am sending a message to server and receiving incoming message from server in another thread but I do not transfer these data to fragment to change the button colors.

How can I transfer incoming tcp data to fragment and change button colors?

Comment: Do you need access to some fragment at ViewPager?

Comment: Please share me if you have any example of it. I do not know it will work. I must need to try it.

Comment: Can you put full code of your examle?

Comment: I think I found a way to get current fragment but I can't change the button color of fragmen in antoher thread.

Comment: Why do you not use UI Thread?

Comment: There is a tcp connection between server and my device. TCP works Async and I need to change button colors when according to incoming message from server. 
If it is possible in UI thread please tell me which method should I use?

Comment: if you have reference on Activity, you can use Activity.runOnUiThread